# Is there a way to set/change the sector size of the device mapper block device created by LVM for a logical volume

Tags: lvm

As I understand it, when LVM activates and creates the device mapper block device for a logical volume, that block device will have a sector size of 4096 (eg. `blockdev --getss /dev/mapper/vg0-lv0` outputs 4096). How can I make it such that the sector size is 512? Is this currently possible with existing tools?

I already know that I can do `losetup --sector-size 512 /dev/mapper/vg0-lv0`. But I want the device mapper block device itself to report a sector size of 512.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The logical volume contain a disk image from a disk with a GPT partition label and 512-byte sector size. If the GPT label is interpreted with sector size being 4096 the partition offsets are wrong.

Comment: These are LVM sector sizes. For example `/dev/mapper/vg0-lv0` could be spread over a mixture of devices - perhaps HD's with 4096 byte sectors and SSD's with 512 byte sectors.

Comment: Yep, the question is not about sector sizes of disks that PVs are located on. I think you missed the part in my comment where I say that the GPT header is _inside_ the LV. This is why the `losetup` is a work around and why I care about the sector size of the LV as shown from `blockdev`.